# not able to insert term programatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add terms using code but it's not added into wordpress. I am using below code to add

```
$term = wp_insert_term('Jogger', 'product_style',0);
```

Every time it return `Invalid taxonomy`. I have check my db and I don't found any entry for this. Even I have check with `term_exists('Jogger', 'pa_style',0);` and it also return 0. Can some have any idea about it.

I am able to add other terms like

```
$term = wp_insert_term('SPORTS', 'product_cat',0);
```

Comment: is `product_style` a `taxonomy`?

Comment: no `product_style` is key for my term

Comment: Second parameter should be taxonomy. Please refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term.

Comment: Thanks Vidhi, You were right. I was thinking in wrong way. to create term we should have taxonomy first. Thanks Again Friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in functions.php

```
        add_action( 'init', 'create_new_taxonomy' );

        function create_new_taxonomy() {
            register_taxonomy(
                'product_style',
                'products',
                array(
                    'label' => __( 'Product Style' ),
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product_style' ),
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                )
            );
        }
```

You can't insert term here because your taxonomy is not registered. So use the above code register it first. Then insert term.

Comment: is this possible to add terms using `wp_insert_term('value', 'key',0);` ?

Comment: yes, I tried $term = wp_insert_term('Jogger', 'product_style',0); and its works for me.

Comment: which version of wordpress you are using?

Comment: It will work in every version.Is it giving any error ?

Comment: I am also working the same version and I checked it. What error you get ?

Comment: I am getting `Invalid taxonomy`.

Comment: Where are you using this line?
$term = wp_insert_term('Jogger', 'product_style',0);

Comment: I am creating import script for woocommerce and here I am trying to use it.

Comment: I mean to say that this taxonomy is used in either for posts or products ?

Comment: Yes, it would be used in products

Comment: so change the 'posts' to 'products' once in my giving answer.Now try the code